# data.table column expression breaks in easyHtmlReport, works in plain knitr

Tags: r, data.table, knitr, easyhtmlreport

I am trying to do some `data.table` manipulations in an `Rmd` file.  The file works just fine with `knit`. However, when I run it through `easyHtmlReport`, it doesn't work: my data.table `by` expressions fail with ‘Error: object 'userId' not found’, where `userId` is one of the columns in my data table that I am using in the `j` expression.  The broken expression is:

```
expt.daystat = expt.users[,list(count=length(userId)),
                          keyby=list(day, status)]
```

As I said, it works fine in plain `knit` but breaks in `easyHtmlReport`.

Comment: I suspect that this is a bug in the `EasyHTMLReport` package. The `knit` function accepts an `envir` argument that needs to be passed along, and inspecting the code for `easyHtmlReport`, it doesnt seem to be doing that. `data.table` does non-standard evaluation and so bugs like this are most likely due to environments. I would suggest you file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks @Ramnath. I've experimented with adding `envir` code to `EasyHTMLReport`, and it does fix the problem. I've reported the issue to the author.

Comment: Hi @MichaelEkstrand - I'd appreciate it if you could provide answer to your question. I'm encountering the issue, and my simplistic solution based on your advice was to add `envir=new.env(parent = .GlobalEnv)` into the control argument which doesn't work so seeing your solution would be helpful!

Comment: @StephLocke I've re-pinged the author about getting the bug fix incorporated into the CRAN version. In the mean time, see answer for the workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ramnath is correct. Line 40 of EasyHTMLReport.R is:

```
knit(input=f,output=md.file)
```

Update this line with:

```
knit(input = f, output = md.file, envir = envir)
```

Update the signature of the function from:

```
easyHtmlReport <-
    function(rmd.file,from,to,subject,headers=list(),control=list(),
        markdown.options=c("hard_wrap","use_xhtml","smartypants"),
        stylesheet="", echo.disable=TRUE, is.debug=F){
```

to:

```
easyHtmlReport <-
    function(rmd.file,from,to,subject,headers=list(),control=list(),
        markdown.options=c("hard_wrap","use_xhtml","smartypants"),
        stylesheet="", echo.disable=TRUE, is.debug=FALSE, envir = parent.frame()){
```

If you don't want to rebuild the package you should be able to make this change using the `edit` function.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to post my alternative solution that I ended up using.  It utilises `mailR` which allows multiple recipients and enables the easy implementation of html without worrying about mime_part commands.

```
library(mailR)
library(markdown)
library(knitr)

from     <-  "me@me.com"
to       <-  "me@me.com"
subject  <-  "Test"
message  <-  markdownToHTML(knit("Test.Rmd"))
send.mail(from,to,subject,message,html=TRUE,smtp=list( host.name="smtp.test.com"))
```

Comment: This post gives you some more info. on using mailR with markdown: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346856/mailr-how-to-send-rmarkdown-documents-as-body-in-email/24355800#24355800